# itunesconnect iphone app status - invalid binary

Tags: iphone, ios4, app-store-connect

Whenever I submit my app to itunesconnect, after about 10 minutes, the status changes to "Invalid Binary" with absolutely no explanation why.

I have searched all over for answers there is non. I even re-installed XCode and App loader.

Note that App Loader doesn't give any errors whatsoever.

I build with XCode 3.2.3 iPhone 4 GM Seed iPhone 4 based SDK iPhone/iPad as a target family

Answer (score 8):

I had the same INVALID BINARY error from iTunes Connect even if Application Loader accepted my binary. The solution was very simple...

Open your info.plist, right-click and check **Show Raw Key/Values**:

- **CFBundleIconFile** = Icon.png (my iPhone 57x57 PNG icon)
- **CFBundleIconFile~ipad** = Icon-72.png (my ipad 72x72 PNG icon)
- **CFBundleIconFiles** = array

  - **Item 0** = Icon.png
  - **Item 1** = Icon@2x.png (my iPhone 4 114x114 PNG icon)
  - **Item 2** = Icon-72.png

Save, clean all targets, build and analyze, compress in Finder and resubmit!

The error was caused because I typed the key "Icon Files". In Raw view, this has mapped to "Icon Files" instead of CFBundleIconFiles. I have Xcode 3.2.3, I guess Xcode 3.2.4 better maps this key identifier.

Good Luck everybody!

Source: [Technical Q&A QA1686: App Icons on iPad and iPhone](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1686.html)

Answer (score 3):

The "invalid Binary" did cost me 4 days to figure out. and because I stumbled over this helpful page, I want to help saving you the valuable time. In my case, in the provisioning portal, a colleague revoked the distribution cetrificate, built a new one and did not let me know. You can use the new certificate for making new prov files, and in the build process, xcode "thinks" everything is all right. which of course is not. Only after uploading to the itunes connect you see the "Invalid Binary" note without further explanantions. The solution was to revoke the certifikate (again) with the whole certificate request procedure and make a new one. Use this as the certificate, and you will be fine - no more uncommented "Invalid Binary" - and if you share tzh eteam agent access to the portal with others, make sure, you let them know and hand over your new .p12 key file.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and here is how I resolved it:

1. The CFBundleIconFile is not listed instead Icon File and Icon Files. Change the Icon File to the Icon Files selection. Now click the left arrow next to the Icon Files label to expand the list. You will see Item 0, select Item 0 and then click the plus button to the right to add another item. You should then see Item 1. Enter your 56x56 icon file name in Item 0 and your 72x72 icon file name in Item 1. Save the info list
2. Since I want this app to be both Iphone/Ipad I choose:

   - Architecture as Standard (you will get a warning but if you change to only armv7 for a no warning build, the binary will be rejected by itunesconnect)
   - Base sdk as 3.2
   - Target Device family as Iphone/iPad
   - iOS Deployment Target as 3.2
3. Now build for app store distribution, compress and upload to itunes connect.

Answer (score 2):

The topic is old but i had the same problem today and maybe my explanation will help somebody in future.

While submitting app by Xcode 4 organizer you have to choose distribution profile. Make sure this is exactly the same profile which you set in build settings (project and target). For almost all my projects i didn't have to change build settings from development to distribution and it was fairly enough to choose distribution only in organizer while submitting. But in one case this resulted "Invalid Binary" error in iTunes Connect.

Comment: Thank you.  This fixed my problem.  It's one of those things where I end up thinking "I'm an idiot" because it seems so obvious now.  Anyway, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Apple has improved the error reporting on this recently and now you will get an email that highlights the problem accordingly.   Just be patient it may take a few minutes to come in.   I received the following email which highlighted the problem:

> Dear Developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent binary submission for "XXX.APP". Before your app can be reviewed, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> Invalid Icon Path - No icon found at the path referenced under key "CFBundleIcons": xxxIcon.png
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page and click Ready to Upload Binary. Continue through the submission process until the app status is Waiting for Upload and then use Application Loader to upload the corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The iTunes Store Team

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. App stucks in "Upload Received" status for more than 5 days. After contacting the Itunes Connect Support with the topics "Manage Your Applications" and "Upload received" and answering unnecessary questions, the App Status changed back to "Invalid Binary". After searching for solutions which recommended to check the icons files I found another tip to check the certificate.

That was my solution: I recreated a distribution certificate with Mac's KeyChaining tool and now used a RSA private key instead of DSA. That helped. I re-uploaded the App and the status changed to "Waiting for Review" few minutes later.

Answer (score 1):

I came here for the same issue, tried the App Launcher update, et cetera.  I tried rebooting and resubmitting a dozen times, manually editing the info.plist again and again.  For me the solution was noticing that there is now an "Icon files" AND and "Icon files (iOS5)" entry.  Check both of these for a bad reference to moved icons.

Answer (score 0):

Did you zip the binary?  Might want to try that.

From the iTunesConnect Developer Guide:

> Application Binary and Small App Icons
>   Keep the file size as small as
>   possible, both for ease of upload
>   through iTunes Connect, and for the
>   end-user’s purchase experience. The
>   binary must be a zipped file, and pass
>   a code sign check upon upload in
>   iTunes Connect.
>
> iPhone and iPod touch:
>   If you are uploading an app to run on
>   iPhone and iPod touch, the binary must
>   include an icon that is 57x57 pixels,
>   which will be displayed on the home
>   screen and the App Store when viewed
>   from the iPod touch and iPhone. You
>   can also optionally include a hi-res
>   icon that is 114x1144 pixels to take
>   advantage of the Retina display on
>   iPhone 4.
>
> iPad: If you are uploading
>   an app to run on iPad, the binary must
>   include two icons: one that is 50x50
>   pixels and one that is 72x72 pixels,
>   which will be displayed on the iPad
>   home screen and the App Store when
>   viewed on the iPad.

Comment: Yes I zipped the binary, submitted it via the App Loader successfully

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, reboot, reboot, reboot.  I ended up rebooting and resubmitting five times (making no other changes, honestly) before my app was accepted.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of other things to try.

if you have an old xcode 3.2 Entitlements.plist file hanging around.
Delete it and recreate > New File > Code Signing > Entitlements.

Check the configuration for Archiving
Product > Edit Scheme > Archive > Build Configuration
Make sure the correct one is selected. (for me Release was selected but I needed Distribution profile - yours may vary)

Answer (score 0):

your Binary final rejected because of some basic reasons.

like,

1)Check For 'icon files' option in info tab of project.

if  your app is Universal icon files should be 4 or <4  *must not more then.
  if  your app is for one device only the icon file should be 2 or <2. *must not more then.
   Icon files should be as per itunes Guide. [itune guide Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)

2)Must check that for splash screen if your app does not have any splash then also  give  blank splash screen.in universal set for both device.

3) if you are updating app then check for binary version of previous uploaded app and your app.your app must have grater version then uploaded.

4) check for Bundle name and version  also.