# iPhone/iPod Touch: Info.plist: Unable to verify icon dimensions, no icon found

Tags: ios, icons, archive, dimensions, app-launcher

The reason I'm posting this is that I have tried all solutions written online and none has worked for me. What is it that I am missing? Anyone can help? 
While validating my app via the Archives tool in xcode 4.6
This is the error messages I am getting:

**iPhone/iPod Touch: Info.plist: Unable to verify icon dimensions, no icon found. You must define CFBundleIcons, CFBundleIconFiles, CFBundleIconFile, or provide a default Icon.png that is 57x57.**

It is also giving me the same error for iPad, though my app is NOT designed for iPad to start with and in the iOS Application Target, Devices is set to iPhone. I don't know why the iPad is included as an error. I even tried to upload an iPad Icon-72.png and still the error is there.

How can I get rid of this error? 
I have Icon.png, Icon@2x.png and Icon-72.png and the icons work fine both on the simulator and the device.

**My Attempts:**

1. In the Build Settings, I set Compress PNG Files to NO. Not resolved!
2. I deleted the images, pushed them again, cleaned, built and
   validated. Not resolved!
3. I tried [this other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658929/itunesconnect-iphone-app-status-invalid-binary). Not resolved!
4. I tried setting "Icons already include gloss" to NO. Not resolved.

**Here's an image of my bugging error:** 
[image]

Comment: Do you have the Icon Files entry in your plist?

Comment: Yes I do! Icon files (iOS 5) are listed as well as Icon files are listed too.

Comment: 1. Delete the Icon Files entry in your info.plist (CFBundleIcons).
2. Delete all of the icons files from your project.
3. Validate your project settings.
4. Add the icons back to the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now here's how I got this finally resolved:

- I didn't find the icons in the .app bundle, I added the icons manually there. 
  To see the contents of the .app bundle, from the Organizer, control-click the archive, select "Show in Finder". Then, control-click the .archive file (package) and select "Show Package Contents". Under the Products/Applications directory you should find your app. Control-click your app and select "Show Package Contents". Your icon files should be present.
- I created a new archive. 
  Product->Archive to create a new archive,
  then selected the new archive in the Organizer before trying to validate

Those two solutions worked together, adding the icons in the .app bundle and creating a new archive all together has validated the app and I can see the icons now good. Finally worked!

Answer (score 2):

Exactly same problem happened for me. Finally resolved by changing valid architecture in target.

Remove i386,armv6 from Valid architecture if exists. Not able to support armv6 and armv7s.

See this image:  http://postimage.org/image/pxz2fyij5/

Also clear Derived Data from xcode.

Comment: I couldn't find i386,armv6. I only found armv7 and I removed it. Cleaned, Cleared Derived Data, Build then tried Validating again but it is not resolved!! 
What am I missing? This is taking too much time and effort and seriously making me hate this whole xcode thing!! 
Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check out your info.plist and add all necessary Icon names. Also check if any unused icon name found.

Here is icon file size:

```
Icon.png          : 57x57
Icon@2x.png       : 114x114
Icon-72.png       : 72x72
Icon-ipad@2x.png  : 144x144
Icon-Small-50.png : 50x50
Icon-Small.png    : 29x29
iTunesArtwork     : 1024x1024
```

Look at this screenshot of info.plist for more details.

[image]

Comment: My app isn't for iPad, why do I have to create icons for that? I only have two png icons there. Icon.png and Icon@2x.png, Do I have to create one for iTunesArtwork? cause that one I already uploaded to the itunesconnect website.

Comment: Its optional and no need to use iPad Icon if no support for iPad. Other errors are solved right?

Comment: No, it hasn't been resolved! I already had these icons listed in my info.plist and it didn't work. Do I have to add the iTunesArtwork image as well? It hasn't complained about it in the first place.

Comment: also added to xcode target? goto simulator build and open and see there copied icon files.

Comment: Can you explain this? I have my target Device: iPhone. The icons work well when I run it on the simulator. Any thing else I am missing here?

Comment: Is that works in real device? just once check icon image names..its case sensitive.

Comment: icon images are in the right case. Icon.png and Icon@2x.png and yes it works on the real device really well. It is just breaking while on Organizer > Archive > Validate and Organizer > Archive > Distribute

Comment: Is that works in real device? Also listed in Xcode summary page? http://s15.postimage.org/8yop35ee3/upload.png

Comment: icon images are in the right case. Icon.png and Icon@2x.png and yes it works on the real device really well. It is just breaking while on Organizer > Archive > Validate and Organizer > Archive > Distribute

Comment: I posted it there as well and still no reply. Just wondering that could it be that when gimp is resizing and saving the image that Xcode has an issue with the file format saved from gimp?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26407/discussion-between-joe-saad-and-guru)