# I am having an error regarding icons dimensions while i am uploading my app on app store

Tags: ios, upload, icons, dimensions

I have all the icons in my app but when i try to upload the app it gives me the following error

I have tried many solutions like adding and deleting icons again and again and making icon files entry in info.plist. But nothing is working its because i am new to iOS.

Comment: update the question with your error log and screen shot of icons added in your bundle .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469356/iphone-ipod-touch-info-plist-unable-to-verify-icon-dimensions-no-icon-found

I have the same problem but unable to resolve

Comment: the user can't post a screenshot of the error because his/her rep is too low, but they can copy/paste the list of the errors in an edit for this question.

Comment: I resolved the error and was able to submit my app on app store but they pointed out the following error

Invalid File Name - Your package contains a file 'AR Reader .app/AR Reader ' with a name that contains leading or trailing whitespace characters.

Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page and click "Ready to Upload Binary." Continue through the submission process until the app status is "Waiting for Upload." You can then deliver the corrected binary.